# How to stop control for few seconds in java?

Tags: java, controls

first if condition executes and then one method called and then i stop the control for 3 seconds ,then next if condition executes again one method called and stop control for 3 seconds likewise i executed 8 if conditions.But i get wrong output. What happened in my output is, sometimes method called before completion of control stop method.

Here my  coding and output. Give one solution

```
                  package com.example;

                import java.util.Timer;
                 import java.util.TimerTask;

               public class TimeBetween {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SecondClass obj = new SecondClass();

    int a = 5;
    int b = 3;
    int c;
    System.out.println("Timer Starts");
    if (a == 5 && b == 3) {
        c = a + b;
        System.out.println("-----------Addition:" + c);
        obj.secondClassMethod();
        timeControlMethod();

    }

    if (a == 5 && b == 3) {
        c = a - b;
        System.out.println("-----------Subtraction:" + c);
        obj.secondClassMethod();
        timeControlMethod();
    }

    if (a == 5 && b == 3) {
        c = a * b;
        System.out.println("------------Multipication:" + c);
        obj.secondClassMethod();
        timeControlMethod();
    }
    if (a == 5 && b == 3) {
        c = a % b;
        System.out.println("-------------Modulo:" + c);
        obj.secondClassMethod();
        timeControlMethod();
    }

    if (a == 5 && b == 3) {
        c = a + b;
        System.out.println("************Addition:" + c);
        obj.secondClassMethod();
        timeControlMethod();

    }

    if (a == 5 && b == 3) {
        c = a - b;
        System.out.println("************Subtraction:" + c);
        obj.secondClassMethod();
        timeControlMethod();
    }

    if (a == 5 && b == 3) {
        c = a * b;
        System.out.println("***************Multipication:" + c);
        obj.secondClassMethod();
        timeControlMethod();
    }
    if (a == 5 && b == 3) {
        c = a % b;
        System.out.println("***************Modulo:" + c);
        obj.secondClassMethod();
        timeControlMethod();
    }

    System.out.println("Timer  Ends");

}

   private static void timeControlMethod() {

    long getCurrentTimeInMilSec = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long setEndTime = getCurrentTimeInMilSec + 3000l;
    System.out.println("Time method waiting for 3 sec........");
    while (setEndTime > System.currentTimeMillis()) {

    }

}
       }

        class SecondClass {
         public void secondClassMethod() {
    System.err.println("Inside of SecondClass method");

          }
     }
```

OUTPUT:

```
                   Timer Starts
                   Inside of SecondClass method 
                    -----------Addition:8
                   Time method waiting for 3 sec........
                   -----------Subtraction:2
                    Time method waiting for 3 sec........
                    Inside of SecondClass method
                    ------------Multipication:15
                    Inside of SecondClass method
                    Time method waiting for 3 sec........
                     -------------Modulo:2
                    Time method waiting for 3 sec........
                    Inside of SecondClass method
                   ************Addition:8
                    Time method waiting for 3 sec........
                     Inside of SecondClass method
                      Inside of SecondClass method************Subtraction:2
                      Time method waiting for 3 sec........

                    ***************Multipication:15
                    Time method waiting for 3 sec........
                    Inside of SecondClass method
                      ***************Modulo:2
                     Time method waiting for 3 sec........
                     Inside of SecondClass method
                      Timer  Ends
```

Comment: I will suggest you try to take advantage of Java thread wait and notify mechanism..playing with thread sleep method is not a good solution

Comment: I tried running your code 4 times and each time I get consistent output where the order of text printed into the console is as per invocation order on the source code. Also I don't get any indentation as you have in your output above. How did you run your program?

Comment: through eclipse ide i run the program

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to sleep and do nothing, then you can use

```
Thread.sleep(x);
```

where x is the time in milliseconds.

`Thread.sleep` is considered bad when people try to fix a race condition using it in a multi-threaded environment. For such situtaions, java `wait/notify` model is a much better choice. But I believe in your case, it is valid to use `Thread.sleep` as you are not trying to solve a race condition and simply want your execution to stop for the desired time.